# Wamp server doesn't show my local website

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, wamp

I have checked the rewrite module on Apache modules, I have downloaded the files from a local server with Filezilla and when I try to type on chrome: `localhost/"myprojectname"` it shows me this message:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Would you edit in the PHP code you are using? If there's a lot, please trim it down to the section of interest. The issue may be pointed to by a line number specified in the error message. As it stands, we can only say that you have got your database credentials wrong, and that you should check your username and password - anything else would be guess-work.

Answer (score 1):

That error message is generated my MySQL.

You'll need to find the local file within the website that contains your MySQL configuration / login information and update it to reflect the proper credentials for your WAMP MySQL installation.

Comment: I think the default WAMP folder is C:\wamp with a bin subfolder that contains folders for Apache, MySQL, and php.  I believe the configuration files for each of the WAMP components are in the bin subfolder for that component.  Best to make a copy before making changes.  There is quite a bit of information available for the various configuration files via a search.

Comment: This was more about finding the php file that is being loaded up with login credentials.